# Deploy Prerender Service on local

Tags: prerender

I installed prerender middleware on my asp mvc + angularjs project, it connects to service.prerender.io but I want to use my own prerender service.
how can I run prerender service on port 3000 on my local server ?

Answer (score 3):

The code for the open source server is here: [Prerender Github](https://github.com/prerender/prerender)

The installation instructions are there on the Github page. You would then set the `prerenderServiceUrl` property of your middleware to point it to `http://localhost:3000` or wherever you are running your own Prerender server and all requests would go there instead of our hosted service.

Answer (score 0):

for nginx users, you can setup upstream to pass into proxy_pass directive.

```
upstream prerender_server {
    server localhost:30000;
}
```

in your localtion block :

```
  ....
  proxy_pass http://prerender_server;
  ....
```